# Can not swipe to the next page and zoom in properly after implementing onScale method

Tags: java, android

I came across two problems.

1. can not swipe to the next page/screen since I've implemented `onScale`
2. when zooming in I can not move to the corners (only the centre is zoomed in)

   class ScaleListener implements ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener {

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
       scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

       if (scaleFactor > 2) scaleFactor = 2;
       else if (scaleFactor < 1.0f) scaleFactor = 1.0f;
       scaleFactor = (scaleFactor * 100) / 100;
       viewPager.setScaleX(scaleFactor);
       viewPager.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
       viewPager.setPivotX(detector.getFocusX());
       viewPager.setPivotY(detector.getFocusY());
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
   }
   ```

   }